# Custom string variable in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find two or more variable in a string with Regex. For instance I have an string like this "Result = Num + 2 ( 6 * Count )". I want to find out if "Result", "Num" and "Count" are in this string or not. Suppose that I want to build a small compiler and these Strings are my reserved words and I want to use regex for this checks.

Case sensitive is more important for me. For example if client inputs "num" or "count" in a string, the method must return false.

How can I do it in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to use arbitary word collection

```
var words = new [] { 
                     "Result",
                     "Num",
                     "Count"
                   };

var source = "Result = Num + 2 ( 6 * Count)";
var regex=new Regex(string.format(@"\b(?<words>(?-i){0})\b", string.Join("|",words));
var results = (
            from m in regex.Matches(source).OfType<Match>()
            select m.Groups["words"].Value
            ).ToArray();
```

`results` will be an array of matching words

However if as you state as your comment in another answer you are building a small compiler you would be better off building a tokenising engine.  For example [Build a Better Tokeniser](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Regular_Expression_Recipes%E2%80%94A_Better_Tokenizer)

Comment: Thanks Bob, Great answer. How can develop it to some other variables? Can it develop dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one of the first things in a Regex tutorial..

```
string expression = "Result = Num + 2 ( 6 * Count )";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(expression, "[a-zA-Z]+")) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```